# Apply ternary operator inside an expression which uses a filter

Tags: angularjs

this works:

```
{{ boolean ? String1 : String2 }}
```

this doesn't:

```
{{ boolean ? String1 | weirdoFilter : String2 | weirdoFilter }}
```

**How can I apply filters to ternary expressions ?**

edit: Maybe single quotes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it with parenthesis :

```
{{ (boolean ? String1 : String2) | weirdoFilter }}
```

Answer (score 5):

... if you make a function in your view, then it becomes easier to do logic in your controller using real life javascript (instead of more limited angular expressions)...

```
{{ mySpecificThing(String1,String2) }}
```

... then in controller ...

```
$scope.mySpecificThing = function(item1, item2){
    return boolean ? $filter('weirdoFilter')(item1) : $filter('weirdoFilter')(item2);
}
```

As a general pattern, I think it is favourable to always keep your logic away from your templates.

Comment: I agree that's the reason why I upvoted your answer, in my current situation I had to make the changes inside the view therefore the other answer to that case is more suited.